# Uniform convergence of $\sin\left ( {\frac{1}{n^{3}x}} \right )$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

I ran into this question and im not sure how to solve it:

Check uniform convergence of:

$$f_{n}(x)=\sin\left ( {\frac{1}{n^{3}x}} \right )\quad \;x\in (0,1]$$

I tried finding the supremum of the function and then take the limit as $n \to\infty$. I got the answer $1$ which means that it is not uniform convergence, but there is no use of the specific bounding of $x\in (0,1]$ in this way, which means there is no uniform convergence for any $x$.

on the other hand, I found that when $x\in [1,\infty)$ there is uniform converegnce.

Please help me understand where is the use of the specific boundry of $x\in (0,1]$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is $f(x) = 0$. For $N \in \mathbb N$, let $x_N = 1/N^3$. This is always possible since $x \in (0, 1]$. We have $f_N(x_N) = \sin(1)$. By letting $\epsilon < \sin(1)$ we see that $f_n(x)$ cannot converge uniformly on $x \in (0, 1]$.

On the other hand, if $x \in [1, \infty)$, we have $0 \le \dfrac{1}{n^3 x} \le \dfrac{1}{n^3} \le 1$. Hence:
$$
\left|f_n(x)\right| = \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^3 x}\right)\right| \le \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right|
$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can make $n$ large enough so that:
$$
\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right| < \epsilon
$$

Thus, $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $x \in [1, \infty)$.

Comment: thanks, great answer.

just one question - how come when i tried finding the supremum, it came out 1 for any x which means it does not converge uniformly for any x? what did i do wrong?

Comment: @user76508 To show that the supremum is $1$, you have to use the fact that $x \in (0, 1]$. If $x \in [1, \infty)$, the supremum is not $1$ as illustrated by my answer. In other words, the supremum changes depending on the domain of $x$ (as one would expect).

Comment: @Anyman i just tried to find the supremum of the function again. i took the derivative and said it is equal to 0. i found this happens at $x=\frac{2}{n^{3}\pi}$.
i put this in the function and i got limit as $n\to \infty$ of $sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ which is 1. for any x.

Comment: @user76508 This is correct. What I did was slightly different. I simply showed that no matter what $N$ we choose, we will always have a value of $x$ that is too far away from $0$ for uniform convergence to be possible. Showing that the supremum is fixed regardless of $n$ is another way to do it, but it's a bit more involved.

Comment: @user76508 And to repeat my initial point, both arguments work only when $x \in (0, 1]$. This is because both $1/n^3$ and $2/(\pi n^3)$ are in $(0, 1]$.

Comment: @Anyman thanks, i finally got it.